# JQuery if command not working

Tags: jquery, if-statement, click, var

I'm trying to make it so the color changes once the currentLetter variable gets to 34 but for some reason it just changes the color as soon as i click.

```
var isStart = false;
var letterString = "D0E916C0A8CED059359C02DARREN KORB - PALE WATCHERS.mp3E415AAB0014400E104B40DE96A0";
var letters = letterString.split('');
var currentLetter = 0;


function changeLetter() {
    $("#t-" + currentLetter).text(letters[currentLetter - 1]);
    currentLetter += 1;

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var image = $('#content').click(function () {
        if (!isStart) {
            isStart = true;
            setInterval(changeLetter, 100);
        }


        if (currentLetter == 34) {
            $("#t-1").css("color", "red");
        }

    });
});
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to declare `var isStart` before using it in document ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your if into the changeLetter function:

```
function changeLetter() {
    $("#t-"+currentLetter).text(letters[currentLetter-1]);
    currentLetter +=1 ;
    if (currentLetter == 34) {
       $("#t-1").css("color", "red");          
    }

}
```

Note that you should keep the interval ID otherwise you wont be abble to stop it.

```
var isStart = false;
var letterString = "D0E916C0A8CED059359C02DARREN KORB - PALE WATCHERS.mp3E415AAB0014400E104B40DE96A0";
var letters = letterString.split('');
var currentLetter = 0;
 var intervalID;

function changeLetter() {
    $("#t-"+currentLetter).text(letters[currentLetter-1]);
    currentLetter +=1 ;
    if (currentLetter == 34) {
           $("#t-1").css("color", "red");    
           clearInterval(intervalID);       
        }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var image = $('#content').click(function() {
        if  (!isStart) {
            isStart = true;
           intervalID =  setInterval(changeLetter, 100);
        }
    });
});
```